# how to increase the performance of loading an image from url

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i m loading an image from an url and displaying it in imageView .i m using NSBLockOperation to load the image and it  runs in the background and it takes time to load the image in imageview..is there any way to increase the performance so that it takes less time..below is the code.

```
NSOperationQueue *queue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
NSBlockOperation *operation=[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSString *imagefile = [banner1 objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:imagefile];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
    UIImage *ui=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    bigbanner.image=ui;
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    bigbanner.alpha=0.0;

}];
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{bigbanner.alpha=2.0;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}];

[queue addOperation:operation];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that your limiting factor is the image download.
Loading an image and placing it on screen happens quite fast on iOS.

Other than changing your three second fade-in to a shorter interval, I think you're stuck.

You might try doing the download using [NSURLRequest], but I doubt you'll notice a major difference.

I'd say your options are (ranked in order of speed):

1. cache or include images in your bundle (don't download).
2. make your images smaller
3. increase the speed of your server

Also: a side note, and hopefully someone else passing through can answer this... is setting the image property of a UIImageView from a non-main-thread safe to do? I was under the impression that everything that happened to the UI was supposed to happen on the main thread.

Comment: it goes like dis once the image gets downloaded the fade in effect occours and it works perfectly fine..the only problem is the download of image from url..i ll tag my screenshot

Comment: @kingston downloading images is slow. Find ways to solve this by reducing the number of images you load, the size of the images you load, and by making the app responsive and useful while the images load.

Comment: @Kenny_Winker Usually works but it is bad practice because you don't really know what UIKit is up to underneath. You can dispatch async the setting to the main thread instead, the decompression should still be on the background. Related to this question is http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/ Basically decompressing an image is that slow. You can force decompression to create a cached version, but on this case I understand he wants to download, uncompress, and show right away. Hope someone can give a better answer.

Comment: Btw surprisingly, decompression is by far slower than disk access. Probably slower than network access too if your iPhone is already using the network.

Answer (score 1):

Give ASIHTTPRequest a try, just maybe loading image asynchrony in the background can improve speed when loading several images at the same time, checkout ASINetworkQueue

Didn't try it but here it is:

```
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASINetworkQueue.h"

-(void)loadImages
{
    ASINetworkQueue * asiNetworkQueue = [ASINetworkQueue queue];
    [asiNetworkQueue setDelegate:self];
    [asiNetworkQueue setShouldCancelAllRequestsOnFailure:NO];

    for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some_url"];

        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageRequestFinished:)];
        [request setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"id"]];
    }
    [asiNetworkQueue go];
}

-(void)imageRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];

    //Use the id to match the request with a specific UIImageView
    int imageId = [request.userInfo objectForKey:@"id"];
    //imageViewArray[imageId].image = image;
}
```

//------------------------------------
EDIT - Loading a single image
//------------------------------------

```
-(void)loadImage:(NSString*)imagePath
{
    //_activityIndicator.hidden = FALSE;
    //[_activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSURL*imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imagePath];

    ASIHTTPRequest* request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:imageURL] autorelease];

    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestDidFailed:)];
    [request setDidStartSelector:@selector(requestDidStarted:)];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDidFinished:)];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous]; 

}

- (void)requestDidFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    //_activityIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
    //[_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[request responseData]];

    // NSLog(@"image download finished");
}

- (void)requestDidFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    //NSLog(@"Loading Image Failed");
    //_activityIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
    //[_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)requestDidStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    //NSLog(@"image download started");
}
```

Comment: I m loading only one single image (the big banner at the top)...cud u help me implement in the above code...thanks again

Comment: I edited the answer to include the code for a single asynchronous call . To setup ASIHTTPRequest Lib visit - http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned there's not much that you can do if the limiting resource is network speed. If the files aren't too large (and they don't look to be) you could preload them before the user reaches the page. For example, if there's only a few banners you could start loading all of them right when the app starts. If there's too many to do that you could try making educated guesses - e.g. If the user lands on a screen that can only lead him to 4 possible banners start downloading them all when the user lands on that screen in preparation for when they make their selection. Finally you should cache the banners once downloaded so you only have to pay for the network access once.

Hope that helps.

Comment: mkay..will there be any difference if i use ASIHttpRequest or NSURLRequset of loading image from url?

Comment: I've used both an haven't noticed much difference in terms of speed (although I haven't done any kind of formal tests). ASIHttp is more feature rich but requires a bit new setup to use. Which one you use depends on what needs you have aside from URL downloading which both will do a fine job with.